# Functoriality of Gysin homomorphism defined via Thom construction

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology

I want to understand how Gysin homomorphism (in multiplicative cohomology theories) for proper oriented maps between smooth manifolds works and in particular prove some facts about it. I am almost constantly confused when reading about it, so it might be the case that what I wrote below makes no sense.

Let $h$ be a multiplicative cohomology theory.

If $p:E\to X$ is a $n$-dimensional real vector bundle. The Thom class of a bundle $E$ is an element $U_E\in\tilde{h}^n(Th(E))$ s. t. for every inclusion of a fiber $i_x:p^{-1}(x)\to E$ a class $i^*(U_E)\in\tilde{h}^n(p^{-1}(x))\cong h^n((p^{-1}(x))^\bullet)$ is an $h^*$-orientation of a vector space $p^{-1}(x)$ (that is, some generator of $\tilde{h}(-)$ of its one-point compactification).

Let $p:E\to Y$ be a $n$-dimensional smooth real vector bundle over a manifold $Y$ and $i:X\to E$ be a smooth embedding s. t. $p\circ i:X\to Y$ is a proper map.

When we fix a standard Riemannian metric on $E$, we define the normal bundle $TX^\perp\cong \nu(i)$ inside the tangent bundle $TE$.

At some neighborhood of a zero-section $Z$ inside $TE$ we have a well-defined exponential map $exp: Z\to E$. There is a compression diffeomorphism $h:TE\to Z_1\subset Z$ which commutes with the projection $\pi: TE\to E$.

Putting those structures together, we obtain the following tubular neighborhood of $X$ in $E$:

$\begin{matrix}
T^\perp X\cong\nu(i) & \xrightarrow{\zeta} &Th(E)\\
\\
h \bigg\downarrow&  & \bigg\uparrow \subset\\
\\
Z & \xrightarrow[]{\ \ \ \ exp\ \ \ \ } & E
\end{matrix}$

If the dimension of $E$ is big enough, the homotopy class of the map given above is uniquely determined (we are in the stable range).

Finally, we construct $\hat{i}$ as follows

$\begin{matrix}
Th(E) & \dashrightarrow &Th(\nu(i))\\
\\
 \bigg\downarrow&  & \bigg\uparrow \cong\\
\\
Th(E)/(Th(E)\setminus \zeta(\dot{\mathbb{D}}(\nu (i))) & \xleftarrow{\ \cong\ }& \mathbb{D}(\nu(i))/\mathbb{S}(\nu(i))
\end{matrix}$

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a smooth proper map and $d:=dim(Y)-dim(X)$.

For some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is an embedding $emb: X\to\mathbb{R}^k$ (and all of them are in the same homotopy class), hence the map $$\tilde{f}:X\ni x\mapsto (f(x),emb(x))\in Y\times\mathbb{R}^k$$ is also an embedding.. If there exists a Thom class $U_{\nu(\tilde{f})}\in \tilde{h}^{k+d}(Th(\nu(g)))$, we say that $f$ is $h^*$-orientable.

In such case, we can apply the construction described above to the map $\tilde{g}$ and define Gysin homomorphism $f_\natural$ as follows:

$\begin{matrix}
h^*(X) & \dashrightarrow & h^{*+d}(Y)\\
\\
\cup U_{\nu(\tilde{f})}\bigg\downarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ &  &\ \ \ \bigg\uparrow\cong\\
\\
h^{*+k+d}(Th(\nu(\tilde{f}))) & \xrightarrow[]{h^*(\hat{\tilde{f}})} & h^{*+k+d}(Th(Y\times\mathbb{R}^k))
\end{matrix}$

I need to check that this is a functorial construction. For this to be true, we need to choose Thom classes coherently, but I ignore that problem here (for example, when $h^*(-)=H^*(-,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, this is irrelevant)

Furthermore, I need to show that for the cartesian diagram

$\begin{matrix}
V_0\times_Y V_1 & \xrightarrow[]{\ \ \ \ \overline{g}\ \ \ \ } & V_0\\
\\
\overline{f}\bigg\downarrow&  & \bigg\downarrow f\\
\\
V_1 & \xrightarrow[]{\ \ \ \ g\ \ \ \ } & Y
\end{matrix}$

with $f$ $h^*$-orientable and $f$ and $g$ being transversal, the following diagram is commutative

$\begin{matrix}
h^*(V_0\times_Y V_1) & \xleftarrow[]{\ \ \ \ h^*(\overline{g})\ \ \ \ } &h^*(V_0)\\
\\
\overline{f}_\natural\bigg\downarrow&  & \bigg\downarrow f_\natural\\
\\
h^*(V_1) & \xleftarrow[]{\ \ \ \ h^*(g)\ \ \ \ } & h^*(Y)
\end{matrix}$

For the first of these goals, I consider the following diagram (indices corresponding to the grading and number of iterations of the suspension isomorphisms are omitted, because they made diagram too messy and can be deduced from the context)
[image: diagram]
where non-obvious maps are given by the multiplication by Thom classes.

The commutativity of the triangle in the lower right corner is obvious and the commutativity of the upper left triangle is reduced to expressing the Thom class of the bundle $B$ when given Thom classes of bundles $A$ and $A\oplus B$.

I have a problem with describing how the map $F$ works, even though I have some kind of a geometric idea in mind - it seems to be an application of construction described in the definition of a Gysin homomorphism to the map $Th(\nu(\tilde{f}))\to Th(\Theta^d\to Y)$.

To show that the square in the middle row commutes, probably I should rewrite it as

$\begin{matrix}
\tilde{h}(Th(\nu(\tilde{f}))) & \xrightarrow{} &\tilde{h}(Th(\nu(\tilde{f})))\otimes \tilde{h}(Th(\tilde{f}^*\nu(\tilde{g}\times i))) & \xrightarrow{} & \tilde{h}(Th(\nu(\tilde{gf})))\\
\\
 \bigg\downarrow&  & \bigg\downarrow & &\bigg\downarrow\\
\\
\tilde{h}(Th(\theta^d\to Y)) & \xrightarrow{}& \tilde{h}(Th(\theta^d\to Y))\otimes \tilde{h}(Th(\nu(\tilde g))) & \xrightarrow{} &\tilde{h}(Th(\theta^d\oplus \nu(\tilde g)\to Y))
\end{matrix}$

and invoke functoriality and commutativity of $h$ and the same reasoning should apply to the middle square in the third row. Commutativity of the square in the left bottom corner should be similar to the commutativity of the upper triangle - again this is about choosing coherently Thom classes for $A, B$ and $A\oplus B$. Finally, commutativity of the triangle in the middle row is a consequence of the construction $\hat{i}$ given above.

For the proof of the claim about the cartesian square, I rewrite it in the following form
$\begin{matrix}
h^*(V_0\times_Y V_1) & \xleftarrow[]{\ \ \ \ h^*(\overline{g})\ \ \ \ } &h^*(V_0)\\
\\
\cup U_\nu\bigg\downarrow\cong&  & \cup U_{\nu(\tilde{f})}\bigg\downarrow\cong\ \ \ \ \ \\
\\
\tilde{h}^*(Th(\nu(\tilde{\overline{f}}))) & \xleftarrow[]{\ \ \ \ ???\ \ \ \ } & \tilde{h}^*(Th(\nu(\tilde{f})))
\\
\tilde{h}^*(\hat{\overline{f}})\bigg\downarrow\ \ \ \ &  &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \bigg\downarrow \tilde{h}^*(\hat{f})\\
\tilde{h}^*(Th(\theta^{d'}\to V_1)) & \xleftarrow[]{\ \ \ \ h^*(G)\ \ \ \ } &\tilde{h}^*(Th(\theta^d\to Y))\\
(\Sigma^{d'})^{-1}\bigg\downarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ &  &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \bigg\downarrow (\Sigma^d)^{-1}\\
h^*(V_1) & \xleftarrow[]{\ \ \ \ h^*(g)\ \ \ \ } &h^*(Y)\\
\end{matrix}$

Transversality implies $\nu(f)\cong g^* \nu (f)$, which obviously should be used somehow, but I don't know how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.